# Java proficiency for Android development

Tags: android

Can one start developing apps in Android with Intermediate proficiency in Java or should a mastery of Java is pretty much prerequisite for Android development ?

Comment: Hi...read this before posting future questions:http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask; As for your question an Intermediate proficiency is more than enough IMO.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is not fit for this site. What does "intermediate proficiency" mean exactly? If you know Java, you can develop in Android, no special knowledge is required.

Comment: As long as you have a mild understanding of Java you can start. But obviously the better you are with Java the easier Android development will be

Comment: @codeMagic This applies to any other language and any platform.

Comment: @m0skit0 yep that's why its not a real question. The point was, the OP  is ok to start. But the question was referring to Java and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be a master at java to start programming Android. The Android developer [page](http://developer.android.com/index.html) provides a good resource for programming apps using the android sdk and is a good resource to use as a reference and for learning the common ways to implement features using the Android APIs. Understanding core java concepts for programming in general is a good start. But everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start developing apps for Android without mastery in Java.

I'm not a master in Java and my problems with Android were never because of my lack of knowledge about Java (only because lack of knowledge in Android API).

Answer (score 0):

As far as you have strong basics of JAVA, what really matters is knowing the OS itself, perfect understanding of the life cycle of the different components is key, learn to navigate the documentation and start doing your own apps would be extremely helpful, Java will help you just to make use of the framework developed to control and manage the components, the way i see it what really matters is knowing the OS, and learn the best practices...

Regards!